# How to access elements inside an ngFor of a child component in the ng-content of the parent component?

Tags: angular, angular9

I have the following components:

component1.html:

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <mat-form-field class="form-control mr-sm-2">
    <input type="search"
           placeholder="text1"
           aria-label="Search"
           matInput
           [formControl]="form1"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           (keyup.enter)= navigateToElement()>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let element of form1Elements | async" [value]="element.name"
        (click)=navigateToElement() (onSelectionChange) = updateElementId(element.id)>
        {{element.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and component2.html:

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <mat-form-field class="form-control mr-sm-2">
    <input type="search"
           placeholder="text2"
           aria-label="Search"
           matInput
           [formControl]="form2"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           (keyup.enter)= "navigateToElement()">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let element of form2Elements | async" [value]="element.properties.name"
        (click)=navigateToElement() (onSelectionChange) = updateElement(element.geometry)>
        {{element.properties.name}}
          <span *ngIf="element.properties.postcode">, {{element.properties.postcode}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="element.properties.city">, {{element.properties.city}}</span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

They look very similar. Therefore, I tried to create a component and reuse it. However, `form1Elements` and `form2Elements` are objects with different structure and I don't know how to write this third component. I tried something like this:

component1.html new version:

```
<app-component3 [placeholder]="text1"
  (navigateToElement)="navigateToElement()"
  (updateElement)="updateElementId($event)">
   <div content>
       {{element.name}}               <------ I HAVE A PROBLEM HERE
   </div>
</app-search>
```

component2.html new version:

```
<app-component3 [placeholder]="text1"
  (navigateToElement)="changeMapCenter()"
  (updateElement)="updateLocation($event)">
   <div content>
        {{element.properties.name}}   <------ I HAVE A PROBLEM HERE
          <span *ngIf="element.properties.postcode">, {{element.properties.postcode}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="element.properties.city">, {{element.properties.city}}</span>
   </div>
</app-component3>
```

and finally component3.html:

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <mat-form-field class="form-control mr-sm-2">
    <input type="search"
           placeholder={{ placeholder }}
           aria-label="Search"
           matInput
           [formControl]="form"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           (keyup.enter)= navigateToElement.emit()>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let element of element$ | async" [value]="????" <--- I HAVE A PROBLEM HERE
        <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Now, here I have some problems:

- In component1.html I have `[value]="element.name"` whereas in component2.html I have `[value]="element.properties.name"`. In my component3.html, I don't know what to put. As I mentioned, elements in component1 and component2 have different structure. They come from different services, different requests, etc. One solution, which I find not very nice, is mapping all the input elements in component1.ts and component2.ts to have some fields in common, like the "name" one. I don't like much this solution, but this would solve this problem. However,
- The `ng-content` in component3 is inside an `ngFor` and I don't know how to access the "element" of `"let element of element$"` in component3 inside component1.html (`{{element.name}}`) or `{{element.properties.name}}` etc. in component2.html.

Is there any way or I have to remove the ngFor from component3 and write it both in component1 and component2?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**
I tried to put the `mat-option` in component1 and component2 and `leave mat-autocomplete` in component 3. It compiled but it didn't show the autocomplete elements. It seems `mat-autocomplete` and `mat-option` must be in the same component. Moreover, I can't take away mat-autocomplete from component3 to components 1 and 2, because `input` links to `[matAutocomplete]="auto"`, and they must be also together in the same component. So, it seems i can't separate these almost identical components...???!!!

**UPDATE2**
I created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ehtycc

It does not compile but it can be seen the idea: two components with very similar html and ts files and I'm looking for a 3rd component to extract all the common code.

Comment: Use  @viewchildren in parent

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? If I user viewchilden, will I be able to `split mat-autocomplete` and `mat-option`? Sorry but I don't see how to use it and a small hint would be very helpful!

Comment: Can you show us a project or stackblitz?

Comment: I created it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ehtycc . It is not compiling but I think the problem can be seen: I have two very similar components and I'd like to create a 3rd component with the common parts.